# How can I enable Cors to load Image URL from Javascript, on ASP.NET Webform?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, cors

I'm doing a Webform ASP.NET page, and in the front end I have an asp:Image tag with a default URL, and at its left I have a list box with some elements. When I click on an item of the list, I made code in Javascript with JQuery so that the image URL would change for an Internet specific URL:

```
var img = document.getElementById('<%=ImageProducto.ClientID%>');

$.get(url)
     .done(function () {
         img.src = url;
     }).fail(function () {
         img.src = urlfail;
     })
```

The problem is that the image cannot load because of CORS Policy Error. It said " 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".

So, I've started to search about it, and found some answers saying that I had to enable the CORS on the server side. So i've tried with two ways:

Adding to Web.Config this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

And adding to the Page_Load where I do the change of URL:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "Get");
                Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            }
```

None of them worked, when I click on the item of the listbox, the url still gets stoped by the same CORS error.
I really needed this to work, is there any way of enabling the CORS Policy so I can make this code work? Do I need to install any external libraries, or do anything more on the server side?

Thanks

EDIT: I've also now tried to install the NuGet Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors, and I've done:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

And still nothing

Comment: You don't need to "get" that image to embed it on the page. And simply embedding the image on the page doesn't require anything to do with CORS; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_network_access

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I just change the url, it works yes, but I need to do the get because I'm working with 1500 products on the listbox, and I need to see the ones that doesn't have images, in order to change the url for the fail one, and on that process, I get the CORS error. Do you know anything that can help me? Cheers

Comment: _I'm working with 1500 products on the listbox, and I need to see the ones that doesn't have images, in order to change the url for the fail one, and on that process [...]_ That doesn't sound like an efficient way to  do things... Why don't you use the `onerror` attribute instead?

Comment: Nevermind, I got the solution anyway. I've used a function that returns a promise simulating to add the url to a new image created, and adding two event listeners, one for load and one for error.  Then I just need to check if the promise returns true or false. And it works perfectly, I don't know why you said that. Thanks anyway